# Closures to flat nested objects?

Tags: arrays, swift, closures

I'm starting to learn about closures and want to implement them in a project I'm working on and I'd like some help.

I have a class defined as follows:

```
class MyObject {
var name: String?
var type: String?
var subObjects: [MyObject]?
}
```

And I want to use closures or higher oder functions (something like `flatMap` comes to mind) to flatten an `[MyObject]` and joining all `MyObject` and `subOjects` into one array.

I've tried using `[MyObject].flatMap()` but this operation doesn't return the nested subObjects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to flattening a recursive class structure is with a recursive function.

Here is the class that we would like flattened:

```
public class Nested {
    public let n : Int
    public let sub : [Nested]?
    public init(_ n:Int, _ sub:[Nested]?) {
        self.n = n
        self.sub = sub
    }
}
```

Here is the function that demonstrates how this could be done:

```
func test() {
    let h = [
        Nested(1, [Nested(2, nil), Nested(3, nil)])
    ,   Nested(4, nil)
    ,   Nested(5, [Nested(6, nil), Nested(7, [Nested(8, nil), Nested(9, nil)])])
    ]
    func recursiveFlat(next:Nested) -> [Nested] {
        var res = [Nested]()
        res.append(next)
        if let subArray = next.sub {
            res.appendContentsOf(subArray.flatMap({ (item) -> [Nested] in
                recursiveFlat(item)
            }))
        }
        return res
    }
    for item in h.flatMap(recursiveFlat) {
        print(item.n)
    }
}
```

The heart of this approach is `recursiveFlat` local function. It appends the content of the nested object to the result, and then conditionally calls itself for each element to add their contents as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I just tested this and it works! Accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

First, I would highly recommend making the type of `subObjects` be non-optional. There's rarely a reason for optional arrays. Do you *really* need to distinguish between "no array" and "an empty array?" This is very uncommon. If you make `subObjects` just be an array, you can write what you're describing as a simple recursive function:

```
func flattenMyObjects(myObjects: [MyObject]) -> [MyObject] {
    return myObjects.flatMap { (myObject) -> [MyObject] in
        var result = [myObject]
        result.appendContentsOf(flattenMyObjects(myObject.subObjects))
        return result
    }
}
```

If you need it to be optional, the changes are minor (you'll need to add an if-let or something similar).

Comment: It is definitely a matter of taste, but you could abbreviate this to `return objects.flatMap { [$0] + flattenObjects($0.subObjects) }`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, and I need my subArray to be Optional because its the result of the parsing of a JSON serialization, this is why I accepted @dasblinkenlight answer, as it handles Optionals, this answer works as well too.