# Swift: create a flat array of views from view hierarchy

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, uiview, flatmap

I have a view hierarchy and I need to flatten it into a linear array, say:

`+ rootView 0
  - subView 1
  - subview 2
  + subview 3
    - subview 3.1
    - subview 3.2
  - subview 4`

I need an array of:

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 4]`

I wondered if `map` or `flatMap` can be used, or if I have to use the traditional way like a breadth-first traverse?

Thanks!

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605621/closures-to-flat-nested-objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a recursive function, which you can call on the `rootView`.

```
func flattenSubviews(view: UIView) -> [UIView] {
    
    var flatArray: [UIView] = []
    flatArray.append(view)
    
    for subview in view.subviews {
        flatArray += flattenSubviews(view: subview)
    }
    return flatArray
}
```

.

```
let flattenedViews = flattenSubviews(view: rootView)
```

A slightly more abstract way of writing the above by putting it in an extension:

```
extension UIView {

    func subviewsFlattened() -> [UIView] {
    
        var output: [UIView] = []
        output.append(self)
    
        for subview in self.subviews {
            output += subview.subviewsFlattened()
        }
    
        return output
    }

}
```

And then you can call it on any view:

```
let allViews = someView.subviewsFlattened()
```

Comment: I think we're doubling each parent. Wouldn't that just work?
view.subviews.flatMap { flattenSubviews(of: $0) }